# unexpected/unseen break in nested for loop after one execution : Gaussian elimination

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array

trying to make a C++ code for Gaussian elimination ,so far i reached the point where i have to zero the elements below the largest absolute element, using this code . The problem is that it is only working for only the first element in each row.

```
void Zero(double (&M)[row][column], int C){
  for (int i = C+1; i < row; i++) //to pass throw rows 
  {
    cout << "R" << i + 1 << " = R" << i + 1 << " - R" << C + 1 << "*" << M[i][C] << "/" << (M[i - 1][C]) << endl;

    for (int j = C ; j < column; j++) 
    { 
      M[i][j] = (M[i][j] - (   (M[C][j])  *  (M[i][C]) / (M[C][C])  )   );
    }

  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

main 2D array 4*4 | for this case `C=0`.

```
6   1  -6  -5
2   2   3   2
4  -3   0   1
0   2   0   1
```

-----after run------

```
6   1  -6  -5
0   2   3   2
0  -3   0   1
0   2   0   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given row `i`, your first step is changing `M[i][C]`, then you go on changing `M[i][C+1]` etc. But if you in the first step set `M[i][C]` to zero, which you do, then for later elements you just get effectively `M[i][j]=M[i][j];`.

I suggest either changing the `j`-loop to

```
for (int j = column-1 ; j >= C; j--){}
```

or saving the value of `M[i][C]` before zeroing it out (i.e. before each `j`-loop), and using that in the expression of `M[i][j]=M[i][j]-...` instead of `M[i][C]`.

Comment: thank u . i saved the the value M[i][c] before entering the second for loop it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Same, I'm glad I could help:)